# Java Typecasting & Calling Methods Simultaneously

Tags: java

Very new to Java.

I have a class called `GraphicsObject` and a class `Bug` that extends it.

I have an ArrayList that holds all GraphicsObject in it:

```
private ArrayList<GraphicsObject> gc = new ArrayList();
```

Then I have a function that gets called every frame called updateObjects().

```
public void updateObjects(){
        for(int i = 0; i < gc.size(); i++){
            if(gc.get(i).toString().equals("Bug") ){
                (Bug)gc.get(i).moveNorth();
            }
        }
    }
```

The typecasting fails and the moveNorth() method never gets recognized because the class GraphicsObject does not have that method, only Bug does.

Any solutions?

Comment: PS `new ArrayList<>()`, not `new ArrayList`

Comment: As an aside, you want to check if `gc.get(i)` is a `Bug`, not whether `toString` equals `"Bug"`. Try `gc.get(i) instanceof Bug`.

Comment: i created a toString() function that returns "Bug" and that's how i verified. I wasn't sure how to check the class before. now i know

Comment: If your `ArrayList` only holds `Bug`s, you may want to declare it as `ArrayList<Bug>` rather than `ArrayList<GraphicsObject>`. This will avoid the cast all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there's a few ways you could go about it:

The most appropriate in this case would be

```
    for(int i = 0; i < gc.size(); i++){
        if( gc.get(i) instanceof Bug ){
            ((Bug)(gc.get(i)).moveNorth();
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could add a method to `graphicsObject` and have Bug override it

```
   abstract public void defaultAction();
```

and in Bug

```
    @Override
    public void defaultAction() {
        moveNorth();
    }
```

then in your renderer:

```
    for(GraphicsObject go : gc){
        go.defaultAction();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You must first cast the actual return value of `gc.get(i)` before calling a method on it. The reason you must place the cast in parenthesis is that the type-cast operator in java has a lower [order of precedence](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) than a method call.

```
((Bug)gc.get(i)).moveNorth();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by writing

```
((Bug)gc.get(i)).moveNorth();
```

However, whenever you do this `check then cast` pattern, you are probably not structuring your program correctly.
I would recommend that you instead put an abstract method in your `GraphicsObject` class, lets call it `move()` and let `Bug` and all other `GraphicObject`s override this. Then you can just eliminate the `if` statement, and just write

```
public void updateObjects(){
    for(int i = 0; i < gc.size(); i++){
        gc.get(i).move();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to simply make sure that the the object is cast to a bug, BEFORE moving north.

((Bug)gc.get(i)).moveNorth();

For future reference:

I think the order of operations in java is

1. Anything enclosed in parentesis
2. Method calls
3. Parsing types of objects
4. Postfix (a++ or a--)
5. Multiplication/division
6. Adding/Subtracting
7. Instance of, <, >, or other relational expressions
8. Equals/not equal (==, !=)
9. and/or (&&, ||)
10. any assignment (=, +=, -=, etc etc etc)

Comment: http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php is a good reference for operator precedence.